# SwiftUI animations differ if called from within a VStack or NavigationItem

Tags: swiftui

I've got a very simple `VStack`, based directly off of one of [Paul Hudson's](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-and-remove-views-with-a-transition) excellent SwiftUI samples. There are two lines of `Text`, one hidden. There's a method to toggle an `@State var` which controls the hidden `Text`.

If I call that function from within the `VStack`, it animates properly. If I call it from a `navigationBarItems`, it loses the animation. Am I missing something about how views are composed?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showDetails = false
    func toggleDetails() { withAnimation { self.showDetails.toggle() } }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                Button(action: { self.toggleDetails() }) { Text("Tap to show details") }

                if showDetails { Text("Details go here.") }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Nav Bar"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: 
               Button(action: { self.toggleDetails() }) {
                    Text("Details")
               })
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

[image: Inconsistent Animations]

Answer (score 1):

### Beta 5 Update

It seems beta 5 fixed this problem. Workaround no longer needed.

---

**Workaround for beta 4 and previous versions**

I think the reason it does not work, is because you are calling withAnimation from a different branch of the view tree. The "Details" button and the views that need to be animated are on different branches of the hierarchy. I am just guessing, but it seems to be supported by the workaround I posted here.

If instead of using explicit animations (i.e., **withAnimation**), you use implicit animations on both the VStack and the Text, it works:

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showDetails = false
    func toggleDetails() { self.showDetails.toggle() }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                Button(action: { self.toggleDetails() }) { Text("Tap to show details") }

                if showDetails {
                    Text("Details go here.").animation(.basic())

                }
            }
            .animation(.basic())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Nav Bar"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.toggleDetails()

                }) { Text("Details") })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer, as it seems beta 5 fixed the problem.